# Cakephp form creation gives me missing database table

Tags: forms, cakephp

According to the manual, I should be able to do this which is to leave Model as null

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(null, array('url' => '/recipes/add'));
// or
echo $this->Form->create(null, array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'add')
));
```

But in reality, I got error saying missing database table? Why?

I have my Model which is not directly mapping to any table. Why can't I leave it as null? Something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(null,array('url' => array('my_account','action' => 'change_avatar'),'type' => 'file'));?>
```

Comment: this is not form issue, its from some model issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `false` for the model instead of `null`:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(false, array('url' => '/recipes/add'));
// or
echo $this->Form->create(false, array(
    'url' => array('controller' => 'recipes', 'action' => 'add')
));
```

From the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-forms):

> You can also pass false for $model. This will place your form data into the array: $this->request->data (instead of in the sub-array: $this->request->data['Model']). This can be handy for short forms that may not represent anything in your database.

Answer (score 0):

make a table with name **recipes** in your database. The submitted date from the form will be saved at **recipes** table.

Comment: No db operation involved in my case. I just want to upload a file. How?